# url module in node.js

Tags: node.js, url, module

I'm trying to fetch the **query** information from the url, using:

`url.parse(req.url, true)`

I catch that in the console to see the information and it gives me back this:

[image]

Any ideas on what is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are using express based on `req`?

Comment: `const server = http.createServer( (req, res) => {  ])`  inside the function, I have the url.parse(req.url, true) line to fetch the data. I'm trying to get the query information, which is **nHive: '1'**, yet, I don't understand the [Object: null prototype] statement before it

Comment: And this is the link that I'm using to fetch the url and break it down.  `<a href="/hive?nHive=1">
</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the value ignoring the [Object null prototype] message and it worked as it should.